# Why does $\frac{\frac12 x+\frac18x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac12x-\frac18x^2+O(x^3)}=1+\frac12x+O(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I was reading the solution to a limit through Taylor expansion but did not understand this passage:

$$g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}=\frac{\frac12 x+\frac18x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac12x-\frac18x^2+O(x^3)}=1+\frac12x+O(x^2)$$

Why is this equality true?

Comment: Which part puzzles you: the first, or second equality?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: Take out $1/2x$ as a common factor of the top and bottom

Comment: There are only two terms in NUM and DENOM and then big O starts. A third term would be welcome. Actually, if you would perform long division (literally), you can see where the answer comes from.  $0.5x$ goes into $0.5x$ exactly $1$ time. After subtraction, those $0.5x$ terms cancel and $0.125x^2--0.125x^2=0.25x^2$. Now $0.5x$ goes exactly $0.5x$ into $0.25x^2$ and so that's where the $0.5x$ comes from....

Comment: the term $O(x^3)$ means that the third term is $\alpha x^3$, with $\alpha$ some number and generally you are meant to ignore this term.

Comment: @jim That's pretty misleading actually, the $\alpha$ does not need to be constant, nor does the scaling even really need to be exactly $x^3$ scaling. The actual definition of big Oh is not so complicated and is really what one should use.

Comment: @Ian yes, you are correct, I should have said "I should have said "$f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x\to 0$,if and only if there exist positive numbers $\delta$ and $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le \; M |g(x)|\text{ for }|x - 0| < \delta$. If $g(x)$ is non-zero for values of x sufficiently close to 0, both of these definitions can be unified using the limit superior: $f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x \to 0$, if and only if $\limsup_{x\to a} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| < \infty.$" that I'm sure the user would have found more enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Divide both numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{2}x$:
   $$g(x)=\frac{1+\frac{1}{4}x+O(x^2)}{1-\frac{1}{4}x+O(x^2)}$$
2. Use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-u} = 1+u + O(u^2)$ when $u\to 0$:
   $$g(x)=\left({1+\frac{1}{4}x+O(x^2)}\right)\left({1+\frac{1}{4}x+O(x^2)}\right)$$
3. Expand, stopping at the $x^2$ order (since you have an $O(x^2)$):
   $$g(x)={1+\frac{1}{4}x+O(x^2)+\frac{1}{4}x} = 1+\frac{1}{2}x+O(x^2)$$
   (for the last step, you can also expand completely, and only then remove the terms that are "swallowed" by the $O(x^2)$. This will be a bit longer to do, but may prevent some mistakes in the  computation.)

Comment: Specifically the $1/2$ comes about because you inherently have a $1/4$ in the numerator and a $1/4$ in the denominator and they add when you expand the product.

Comment: Indeed: at the end of the day, it's (up and including linear terms) $g(x) \approx (1+\frac{x}{4})^2$.